# Variable "is not defined" in inline event handler?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, dom-events

I'm working on a chrome extension where it injects HTML into a page and has `onClick` functions to some buttons. Here is the sample code:

Namespace.js

```
/**
 * Namespace for this content script.
 * @const
 */
var namespace = {};

/**
 * HTML text to be injected.
 */
namespace.HTML = '<input type="text" size="2" placeholder="0.50"' +
                 'onkeyup="namespace.enable(event)" />';

document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', namespace.HTML);

namespace.enable = function() {
  alert('Hello World!')
};
```

HTML is getting injected properly but namespace is not getting recognized.
Here's the error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: namespace is not defined
> onkeyup

Any workarounds?

Comment: Has nothing to do with "namespaces". It is simply that `window.namespace` does not exist - in this case because it is a *locally scoped variable* (`var namespace`, presumably inside a function). The cheap hack which "may work" is to remove `var`; but it would be best to avoid using a string-based event handler .. also, `this` will evaluate to the element upon which the inline event handler runs, which might be useful.

Comment: @pst So you suggest adding event listeners? 
btw, Removing var didnot work

Comment: "may work" is not the same as "will work" - it depends on the larger context. But yes, I suggest using non-inline handlers, and perhaps even closures.

Answer (score 0):

It works in Firefox, Chrome and IE 9 when called as:

```
window.onload = function() {
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', namespace.HTML);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Content script is running in a so-called [isolated world](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#execution-environment). It can't

> Use variables or functions defined by their extension's pages
>
> Use variables or functions defined by web pages or by other content scripts

So you may need to inject your namespace as another piece of js to the HTML page as well.

Answer (score 0):

As @zhuzhour has mentioned, a content script is running in an isolated world the JavaScript in the page cannot access the variables defined by your content script.

If you want to do this, you need to inject the JavaScript file in the page as I have outlined in my other answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13037307/315562

In other words, use the following `content.js` file to inject `namespace.js` .

#### content.js

```
injectScript( chrome.extension.getURL( "/" ), "namespace.js" );
function injectScript ( aBasePath, aScriptURL ) {
  var scriptEl = document.createElement( "script" );
  scriptEl.src = aBasePath + aScriptURL;
  scriptEl.async = false;

  (document.body || document.head || document.documentElement)
  .appendChild( scriptEl );
}
```

You can use this as a starting point. If you need to communicate with the Chrome extension, then you need to use `window.postMessage` in the injected JavaScript file to send messages and receive them in the content script.