# Cannot Find JavaScript Namespace

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create namespaces in JavaScript as in the following script:

```
var hlAdmin = hlAdmin || {};

hlAdmin.editCompany = function (src) {
   // function script
}
```

Then I call the function in HTML:

```
onclick="hlAdmin.editCompany(123)"
```

I get a reference error: Cannot find "editCompany".

Anyone know why?

Comment: Are you creating `hlAdmin` outside of any functions?

Comment: Yes, it exists at top of JavaScript file.

Comment: need more code to see the scoping. In the mean-time you could try: `window['hlAdmin'] || (window['hlAdmin']={});` to make sure `hlAdmin` is in the global scope.

Comment: Please create a plunkr or something like that to show the full code. Likely the problem is that hlAdmin is not defined in global scope.

Comment: Since you're using `var` before the hlAdmin, it's being not being created globally. However, my answer also suggests moving this to an event handler, which is considered a better practice.

Comment: @sphanley: *Since you're using var before the hlAdmin, it's being not being created globally* Without any further code from the OP that's a bogus statement.

Comment: If I read their statement that "it exists at top of JavaScript file" to mean that there's no code before this, then I don't see what's bogus? OP is creating a var hlAdmin, not a window.hlAdmin.

Comment: @sphanley: *"it exists at top of JavaScript file"* would *normally* already indicate the variable is in the root-scope of the host (in a browser this is called `window`). You might want to google how `var` works again. (ps. your current answer *also* uses var).

Comment: Fair enough, I was having a dumb brain moment. I see what you mean about needing more code from the OP.

Comment: @sphanley: No problem, we all got some of those moments, however,  then mend your answer *again*: yes, loosing the var most probably solves the problem, but your explanation *why* it solves the problem is in-correct. (it teaches to fish with grenades, instead of bait).

Comment: I'd welcome an edit suggestion, as I still don't follow what's incorrect. Thanks for helping bump me along in the right direction.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/53984/discussion-between-sphanley-and-gitaarlab).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's generally considered bad form to mix inline javascript and non-inline. The preferred way to do this would be to keep all the javascript in one place using an event handler:

```
window.hlAdmin = window.hlAdmin || {};

window.hlAdmin.editCompany = function (src) {
   // function script
}

document.getElementById('yourElementId').onclick = function() {
    hlAdmin.editCompany(123);
};
```

To more specifically address the issue: One thing that could cause this issue is if the `hlAdmin` object is not ending up in the global scope. You stated that this declaration is "at the top of the JavaScript file", but if it's in **any kind** of function (such as a function set to `window.onload`, or the jQuery `$(function() { ... });`) it would not end up in the global scope when declared as a `var`. A variable declared with `var` will **only** end up globally scoped if it's in the root scope, outside of any kind of function. If rather than using `var hlAdmin` you instead use `window.hlAdmin`, this will make sure that even if you're inside a document ready function or something similar, you're creating your `hlAdmin` in the global context, which will fix the problem if it is in fact an issue of scope.

Comment: This only gives an alternative to hook up the function, it does not explore/solve the cause of the OP's problem/question.

Comment: I fleshed it out a bit more to try my best at addressing the little code we've been provided by the OP.

Comment: Whoever downvoted this -- care to explain what's still wrong with the question? I'm trying my best to make it as correct as possible given what info we have to work with.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but (as I explained to you in the comments to the OP's question), you made people/future readers think it is wrong/incorrect to declare a global variable with var while that declaration is being made in the host-scope (effectively what the OP states that he has done), which is *wrong*.

Comment: Understood. I don't mean to be implying that so I'll edit to make my meaning more explicit.

Comment: The two lines of script exist exactly as I have posted them, the first statement being the first line of the file, independent of anything else, and the second being a standalone function. Furthermore, the function works properly without the namespace added.

Comment: Good edit!. (quite a challenge to write a mini-tutorial about var in the least amount of words isn't it ? :) ) @Fred Chateau: *the function works properly without the namespace added*, then we really need more code, or even better (increasing your chance to a solution): setup a simple jsfiddle that replicates your problem and add it to your question, including the browser that gives this result/error. If that process of refactoring your problem leads to the solution, please do share it here.

Comment: It's working in jsFiddle. When using namespaces in the above manner, do functions called inside the namespaced function change scope? For example, will a function inside the namespaced function also take on the namespace?

Comment: @FredChateau: So, the actual answer.. is the difference between your code and your fiddle...

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments I assume the following:

The equivalent script (and scoping is like):

```
<html><head>

</script>
var hlAdmin = hlAdmin || {};

hlAdmin.editCompany = function (src) {
   // error in this script
}
</script>

</head></body>
  <button onclick="hlAdmin.editCompany(123)">Caption</button>
</body></html>
```

In this example `hlAdmin` is indeed in the global scope (the root-scope of the host, called `window` in browsers).
If (in this example) you get reference error: `Cannot find "editCompany"`, then one should look at other error-messages in your (browser's) error-log, because when there is a fatal error in the function for `hlAdmin.editCompany`, then that function will not be created (hence `.editCompany` becomes a property that points to `undefined` instead of a method that points to the function OR `.editCompany` doesn't even exist (depending on engine/error)).

To investigate if you indeed have a scoping-problem you could test this by: `window['hlAdmin'] || (window['hlAdmin']={});` (or some equivalent variant). If that made the code work, then it seems you have some scoping-problem.

Hope these steps help someone in the future.

Comment: The JavaScript is in a separate file with a script link at the top of the html page.

Comment: We really need to see more code then, sorry. Even better (increasing your chance to a solution): setup a simple jsfiddle that replicates your problem and add it to your question, including the browser that gives this result/error. If that process of refactoring your problem leads to the solution, please also report back with the solution.

Comment: Just sprung to my mind (since we are currently looking for a ghost): is the external javascriptfile actually loaded?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

The browsers (at least Aurora and Chrome) are dropping the namespace in the onclick attribute. When you look at the browser html the namespace has just disappeared from the markup.

Comment: Aha! So my suggestion not to use the inline onclick was more to the point than I knew.

Comment: That would be one of the strangest bug's I've heard of in a long time, as that would break a trunk-load of other scripts/websites. You also say (in another comment) "it's working in jsFiddle"...(so if it's the browsers fault, the fiddle wouldn't work either). *(I'd love confirmation about this from one of SO's top-experts.)* Also, if you were injecting html like in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13040413/variable-is-not-defined-in-inline-event-handler, you would have probably told us. Alas, without your source, we can not know what really went wrong.

Comment: FWIW: Just ran this by the experts in the javascript chat. They to claim Chrome doesn't do such a thing (of rewriting your inline event-handlers) and the problem can not be reproduced according to your description. It *must* be something else in your code, so don't 'learn' the 'wrong' lesson from this!